# In NHibernate how would I map an object to only retrieve it's children but ignore them when creating or updating?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

How would one map this object to only retrieve the collection below and ignore it totally when creating or updating the object to the db?

```
 <bag name="children"  table="tb_parent_child" lazy="false">
  <key column="parentID"/>
  <one-to-many class="Child"/>
</bag>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not set lazy to true? Wouldn't that basically do it? And also maybe set cascade to 'none'?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the cascade attribute to none:

```
 <bag name="children"  table="tb_parent_child" lazy="false" cascade="none">
     <key column="parentID"/>
     <one-to-many class="Child"/>
 </bag>
```

should accomplish this. See this [blog entry](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/NHibernateCascadesTheDifferentBetweenAllAlldeleteorphansAndSaveupdate.aspx) for a description of cascade options.

Comment: Thanks, this still nulls out the parentID in the tb_parent_child table if  send an object (with no children in the collection) to be updated

Comment: You can try setting inverse=true.
But why map the collection as a child of the parent at all? You can just retrieve the collection for yourself in code.